# calling sqlite database from the bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I am working with the sqlite database and everything is going well. I added 4 entries in the table, and then added textview on my xib file. Now i want that this data should be fetched from the sqlite database which is placed in the bundle of the project. But i am not getting how to call this database from the bundle to thedirectory path. Please help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: I would recommend you use FMDB: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

First call this method which will check wheter dbfile is stored in documents Directory or not. If not It will write your file to documents directory.

```
-(void)openDatabase {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasefilename.sqlite"];

        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath
                                        error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.",
                      [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath {
    //Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    //First Param = Searching the documents directory
    //Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
    //Expand any tildes and identify home directories.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasefilename.sqlite"];
}
```

Then check in Appdelegate or any other class where you want:

```
if (sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath] UTF8String], &YOUR_SQLITE3_OBJECT) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"database opened successfully");
}
```